# iptables port forwarding in the ohter direction

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, portforwarding

I use linux router for accessing internet via PPPoE. This box has two interfaces: eth0 for internal LAN and eth1 for establish a ppp0-interface on a PPPoE-Modem. For firewalling and port forwarding I use iptables with nat.
This works as expecting: I can go in the internet from the LAN, I can access certain service in the LAN from outside by port forwarding:

```
  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9999 -DNAT --to 192.168.2.10:22
```

(as an example for accessing the ssh-port of a certain machine inside my LAN from outside)
But I want to access a single machine (192.168.8.2) on the WAN-Port eth1 from inside of the LAN:
for this reason, the eth1 is configured as:
`ip addr add 192.168.8.1 dev eth1`

So I can `ssh 192.168.8.2` from the console on the router. This works as expected. but I want to access this also from machines  from the LAN.

```
  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9997 -DNAT --to 192.168.8.2:22
```

but this isnt going to work. I see packets coming from my LAN-side-machine going in on eth0 and addressing 192.168.8.2, but I dont get an answer.
can someone point me to, where my error is?

thanks in advance
Marco

Answer (score 0):

Unless the server (192.168.8.2) knows how to get back to the computers on the LAN (would have to check routing for traffic coming back from that server), you would have to add a **-t nat POSTROUTING** rule on the router to make it **look like** it's traffic that's going out from the router (which I would guess is already accessible from 192.168.8.2). The the traffic would be able to get back to the router when the server is responding and the router would take care of *unNATing* it.

Comment: ```iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o interface-toward-ssh-server -d 192.168.28.2 --dport 22 -j MASQUERADE -m comment --comment "masquerading ssh traffic going to 192.168.8.2 so it comes back to us"```... or something along those lines.